# synchronize bool in all client networking

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm trying to develop a multiplayer game .
I declared a bool variable which must be synchronized by the server.
this is my code :

```
    public GameObject blueBar, redBar;
public GameObject barH, barV;
[SyncVar] public bool localTurn;



void Start ()
{
    localTurn = true;

    if (!isLocalPlayer)
    {
        Cmdbars();
    }

}

void Update ()
{
        OnClick();       
}


[Command]
void Cmdbars()
{


    GameObject bar1 = Instantiate(barH, GameObject.Find("pos1").GetComponent<Transform>().transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    NetworkServer.Spawn(bar1);


}


private void OnClick()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Vector2 origin = new Vector2(
      Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x,
      Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y);

        CmdOnClick(origin.x, origin.y);
    }


}

[Command(channel = 0)]
private void CmdOnClick(float x, float y)
{
    RpcClick(x, y);
}


[ClientRpc(channel = 0)]
private void RpcClick(float x, float y)
{



    Vector2 origin = new Vector2(x, y);
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(origin, Vector2.zero, 0f);

    if (hit && hit.transform.gameObject.tag.Equals("Untagged") && localTurn)
    {
        hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = blueBar.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
        hit.transform.gameObject.tag = "ok";
        CmdclientPlaying();
    }


    if (hit && hit.transform.gameObject.tag.Equals("Untagged") && !localTurn)
    {
        hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = redBar.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
        hit.transform.gameObject.tag = "ok";
        CmdlocalPlaying();
    }
}
```

here are the commands to change the bool

```
[Command]
void CmdlocalPlaying()
{
        localTurn = true;
}

[Command]
void CmdclientPlaying()
{
    localTurn = false;
}
```

everything is going well except the  the bool localTurn change in local only not in all clients.
must change boll after click in object to play alternately between players.

Comment: https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking/networking-player-health?playlist=29690

Answer (score 0):

try to change this if block to include else if

```
if (hit && hit.transform.gameObject.tag.Equals("Untagged") && localTurn)
{
    hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = blueBar.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
    hit.transform.gameObject.tag = "ok";
    CmdclientPlaying();
}
else if (hit && hit.transform.gameObject.tag.Equals("Untagged") && !localTurn)
{
    hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = redBar.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
    hit.transform.gameObject.tag = "ok";
    CmdlocalPlaying();
}
```

when the CmdclientPlaying(); is called it makes the localTurn to false which will trigger the next if statement and make call to CmdlocalPlaying()

Comment: i do that . but the problem is still there . the bool localTurn change only in local no in clients .

Comment: don't know, but worth to try, change the CmdlocalPlaying to CmdLocalPlaying

and CmdlientPlaying to CmdClientPlaying

Answer (score 0):

i changed the code . i call the function to change the bool outside Rpcclick()
and it worked .
but i dont now why it does not work before .